# AWS LexV2 - Intent-Switching - Why do these two attempts behave differently?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

**Way#1** (no code):

[image: simplest intent-switch]

Test (Desired Behaviour):

[image: successful test]

**Way#2** (simple code):

[image: branching intent]

Lambda (C#):

```
public async Task<LexV2Response> FunctionHandler(LexV2Event e, ILambdaContext context)
    switch (e.SessionState.Intent.Name)
    {
        // a load of other cases...
        case "Testing2":
            return Testing2(e, context);
        // some more cases...
    }
}

private LexV2Response Testing2(LexV2Event e, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        return new LexV2Response()
        {
            SessionState = new LexV2SessionState()
            {
                DialogAction = new LexV2DialogAction()
                {
                    Type = "Close"
                },
                Intent = new LexV2Intent()
                {
                    Name = "Testing2",
                    ConfirmationState = "Confirmed",
                    State = "Failed"
                }
            },
            Messages = new List<LexV2Message>() { }
        };
    }
```

Notice, I'm using SessionState.Intent.State = "Failed",
which according to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/paths-code-hook.html), should cause the Code-Hook block to output along its 'Failure' output:

[image: code-hook (aws docs)]

However, these are the outputs I get from the test window:

a.) When "Use a Lambda function for initialization and validation" is checked:

[image: Test 2A]

b.) When it's NOT checked:

[image: Test 2B]

In case it's not clear, test 2 is outputting via the 'Success' output.

Neither of which are the desired behaviour.

I've been working with Lex for only a few weeks now. It's easy enough to set up a bot with just a single intent. But that's extremely limiting. I need to be able to switch intents effectively and in a predictable way. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?